# Linking feature image background to header background

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Complicated question. In my wordpress site I have the single.php page to display each post when selected from homepage. The single.php brings in a custom header-int.php (the header for index.php is different)
each article (post) contains this code

On the index page each 'article' (post) is placed . Each article has the following code The background is the featured image (displayed as thumbnails on the index page)

article.php

```
<?php
if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
$thumbnail_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'my-fun-size' );
$thumbnail_url = $thumbnail_data[0];
}
?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(''); ?>>

  <div class="bg-img-LC" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $thumbnail_url ?>');">

   ... content of article/post ...
```

The single.php brings in content-single.php with

single.php

```
get_header('int'); ?>

<main role="main">

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?> ...
```

content-single.php

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">  ... displays images and text from post
```

header-int

```
<body id="skrollr-body" <?php body_class('container-fluid'); ?> >       

<?php
if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
    $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full');
    echo $large_image_url[0]; // Image Url
}
?>

<div class="jumbotron row" style="border-radius:0px;">
    <header>
        <div class="navbar navbar-custom">
                    ...
```

I want the 'featured image' from the post to be the background of the jumbotron in the custom header-int.php file.

or perhapse a better way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get `feature image` from post then you can display `feature image` using following code :

```
$large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full');
echo $large_image_url[0]; // Image Url
```

You can change second parameter of `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` to `(thumbnail, medium, large, or full)` as per your need.

**Edit**

---

Your `header-int.php` file should be

```
<body id="skrollr-body" <?php body_class('container-fluid'); ?> >       

<?php
if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
    $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full');
    echo $large_image_url[0]; // Image Url
}
?>

<div class="jumbotron row" style="border-radius:0px;background-image:url('<?php echo $large_image_url[0]; ?>');">
    <header>
        <div class="navbar navbar-custom">
                    ...
```

Comment: @user3550879 You can get `feature image` in your `header-int.php` file as well using above code because your `custom header` file already get `post id` when you run single post page.

Comment: where can I put it so that it becomes the background for the jumbotron?]

Comment: I apologize, I'm not super well versed in wordpress. Anywhere? how would I link it to the header jumbo tron

Comment: Can you please copy your header jumbo tron html?

Comment: And also mention where you need to put feature image as background image as well?

Comment: I added more to the header-int.php code with your code lines included. I need it to become the background of the 'jumbotron' as listed in the code as class="jumbotron row"

Comment: similar to how it work within the articles with the code style="background-image:url('<?php echo $thumbnail_url ?>' right now it just shows the link to the image at the top of the screen as a string